# Using a homomorphism to draw conclusions about subgroup indices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been thinking about this problem:

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Assume that $K$ has index two in $G$. prove that either $H \cap K$ has index two in $H$, or $H \subseteq K$.

The suggestion was given to use a homomorphism to prove this fact. I'm unclear on what homomorphism to use, the domain and codomain of the homomorphism, and most of all how a homomorphism would even help me prove this fact about the index of $H \cap K$.

So far, I see that $K$ must be a normal subgroup because it has an index of 2, and that $H \cap K$ is a subgroup since it is the intersection of two subgroups of G. Beyond that, I'm kind of stuck on the how to utilize a homomorphism here. Any help finding a path to a solution (not necessarily the solution itself) and understanding how homomorphisms are useful in these situations would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: What's the connection between normal subgroups and homomorphisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$Consider the quotient group $G/K$, and the homomorphism $\phi : H \to G/K$ given by $h \mapsto h K$.

**Spoiler 1**

> Since $G/K$ has order $2$, there are two possibilities.

**Spoiler 2**

> Either the image of $\phi$ has order $1$, which means $H \le K$.

**Spoiler 3**

> Or the image of $\phi$ is the whole of $G/ K$. By the first isomorphism theorem, $G/\ker(\phi)$ is isomorphic to $G/K$, so that it has order $2$. But it is immediate to show that $\ker(\phi) = H \cap K$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\;H\rlap{\;\,/}\subset K\;$ , then there exists $\;h\in H\;$ such that $\;h\notin K\;$, and thus $\;h(H\cap K)\neq H\cap K\;$ , so

$\;[H:H\cap K]\ge 2\;$ .

On the other hand,

$$H/(H\cap K)\cong HK/K\le G/K\implies [H:H\cap K]\le[G:K]=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the quotient map $\phi \colon G \to G/K$. If $H \not \subseteq K$, then $\phi_{|H}$ will be surjective. Then if we call $\psi := \phi_{|H}$, it is clear that $\ker(\psi) = H \cap K$. By the first isomorphism theorem, $H/(H\cap K) \cong G/K$, and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Second Isomorphism theorem*:

As $K$ is normal i,n $G$, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, and
$$HK/K\simeq H/H\cap K$$is a subgroup of $G/K$. As the latter  has order $2$, $HK/K$ is either $G/K$ or to K/K.

The first case implies $H/H\cap K$ has order two, which is exactly $[H:H\cap K]=2.

In the second case, $HK=K$, which implies $H\subset K$.